# How do I get a handle on a file renamed with regex?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, rename

I'm renaming a file with regex ...

```
f='/path/to/file'
rename 's/(^.*)([ab])(.*)([cd])(.*$)/$1$4$3$2$5/s' "$f"
```

How do I then get a handle on the renamed file so I can process it given I don't know what it is going to be renamed?

Comment: What do you mean by *"get a handle"*? The first argument you pass to `rename` is any perl code. In that perl code, the file name is stored in `$_`, and that's what the perl code needs to modify to set the new name, after which the `rename` perl function (which just calls the `rename()` syscall) is called with the old name and `$_`  (the new name as argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving `rename` a Perl expression (a substitution to be more precise). Instead of giving that expression to `rename`, use Perl to evaluate it, then move your file:

```bsh
f='/path/to/file'
newname=$( perl -pe 's/(^.*)([ab])(.*)([cd])(.*$)/$1$4$3$2$5/s' <<<"$f" )

printf 'New name is "%s"\n' "$newname"
mv -- "$f" "$newname"
```

Or, simply output the new name with the expression and capture it from `rename`:

```bsh
f='/path/to/file'
newname=$( rename 's/(^.*)([ab])(.*)([cd])(.*$)/$1$4$3$2$5/s; print "$_\n"' "$f" )

printf 'New name is "%s"\n' "$newname"
```

This is assuming that you are using the `rename` based on the Perl `File::Rename` module.

Comment: Note that the `s`ubstitution in your first one (using `perl`) acts on every line of the file name (plus a newline added by `<<<`) instead of on the file name as a whole. Maybe better as `perl -sle 'print if s/.../.../s' -- -_="$f"`. Or `perl -sle 'exit 1 unless s/.../.../s; print' -- -_="$f"`

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to submit the task into parts - find a file to be renamed, generate the transformed file name, and then apply it. At this point you know the destination file name so you can then process it further

```
f='/path/to/file'
g=$(printf '%s\n' "$f" | sed -E 's/^(.*)([ab])(.*)([cd])(.*)$/\1\4\3\2\5/')
mv -- "$f" "$g"
echo "Target is $g"
```

You may want to add error checking, such as making sure the target doesn't already exist, that the source does exist, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that'll work.  I just want to voice my huge disappointment in this failing of `rename` not to echo the result.

Comment: It can echo it (see `man rename`), but then you've got to parse the result. Remember that filenames can contain spaces, unprintable characters, and even newlines. It's next to impossible to parse filenames reliably without support from the tool producing them

Comment: Parsing the `-v` option is hacky imo and non trivial.  You would have to parse out "Y" from "X renamed to Y".

Comment: @deanresin [first version of `rename` from over 30 years ago](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/a687059cbaf2c6fdccb5e0fae2aee80ec15625a8/eg/rename), already let you do whatever you want including `print` the name of the file. There's hardly any limitation in `rename` as it lets you run arbitrary `perl` code and `perl` can do virtually anything as it's a full featured programming language.